# OpenJDK release notes: does not include jar specification?

Tags: java, java-11

The [JDK 11 release notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html) say:

> Oracle JDK includes additional Java SE specifications (such as
>   serialization, jar, rmi) and OpenJDK does not.

Anyone knows in what way OpenJDK does not include the jar specification? For sure it can work with jar files and the jar and jarsigner tools are present in the distribution.

Comment: A specification is a file containing formal descriptions of the technology, not a particular implementation. The statement still is strange as Oracle JDK is not shipped with such specifications either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification is just documentation, like a manual. e.g. [The Java language specification](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/11/latestSpec/java-se-11-jls-draft-diffs.pdf).

Binary wise - OpenJDK 11 and Oracle JDK 11 are equal. There is no Java class available in one, and not available on the other.

> From Java 11 forward, therefore, Oracle JDK builds and OpenJDK builds will be essentially identical.

Source: [Oracle Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/oracle-jdk-releases-for-java-11-and-later)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides specifications for topics such as [serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/serialization/index.html), [jar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jar/jar.html) and [rmi](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmiTOC.html).

OpenJDK does not provide such specifications.